# How to calculate date difference using two separate data rows?

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, dataflow

I'm using the LiveChatTranscriptEvent object to try and determine the time difference between the events ChatRequest and TransferredToQueue.  Each Type is a different row on the object so it would look something like this.

| Time | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:06.000Z | ChatbotEstablished |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue |

First I created a filter transformation to only include ChatRequest and TransferredToQueue.

| Time | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue |

In the dataflow I made a compute expression with the fields ChatRequest and TransferredToQueue for easy reference.

**ChatRequest**

```
case
when 'Type' == "ChatRequest" then toDate(Time_sec_epoch)
end
```

**TransferredToQueue**

```
case
when 'Type' == "TransferredToQueue" then toDate(Time_sec_epoch)
end
```

So now my dataset would look like this

| Time | Type | ChatRequest | TransferredToQueue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest | 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | null |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue | null | 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z |

Next I created a compute relative transformation.  Every time the ChatRequest type occurs, calculate the difference between the ChatRequestDat and TransferredToQueueDate

```
case
when 'Type' == "ChatRequest" then date_diff("second", ChatRequestDate, next(TransferredToQueueDate))
end
```

End product would look like this

| Time | Type | ChatRequest | TransferredToQueue | CalculatedField |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest | 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | null | 2 |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue | null | 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | null |

When I run my dataflow it returns the error that there's invalid arguments for function date_diff.  I'm assuming the next() function isn't working. And I can't find any documentation about the next() function.

What is another solution to try and accomplish the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution but I don't believe it's ideal.  If someone has a better way to solve this please let me know.

**I started with my filtered data.  I included PushAssignment in my filter transformation because I wanted to find how long a client was in queue before they were pushed to an agent.**

Sample data

| Time | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue |
| 2021-01-07T15:41:07.000Z | PushAssignment |

**Added a compute expression convert the Time field to epoch seconds**

**SAQL Expression**

```
date_to_epoch(toDate(Time_sec_epoch))
```

Sample data

| Time | Type | TimeToNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest | 1,610,033,702 |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue | 1,610,033,707 |
| 2021-01-07T15:41:07.000Z | PushAssignment | 1,610,034,067 |

**Next I added a compute relative partitioning by key/unique Id then by TimeToNumber.  I created a field that would grab the value of TimeToNumber from the next row.**

**SAQL Expression**

```
next(TimeToNumber)
```

Sample data

| Time | Type | TimeToNumber | SegmentEndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest | 1,610,033,702 | 1,610,033,707 |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue | 1,610,033,707 | 1,610,034,067 |
| 2021-01-07T15:41:07.000Z | PushAssignment | 1,610,034,067 |  |

**Finally I created a another compute expression with a field to calculate the difference between the previous two fields.**

**SAQL Expression**

```
'SegmentEndTime' - 'TimeToNumber'
```

Sample data

| Time | Type | TimeToNumber | SegmentEndTime | EventDuration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:02.000Z | ChatRequest | 1,610,033,702 | 1,610,033,707 | 5 |
| 2021-01-07T15:35:07.000Z | TransferredToQueue | 1,610,033,707 | 1,610,034,067 | 360 |
| 2021-01-07T15:41:07.000Z | PushAssignment | 1,610,034,067 |  | 0 |